# How to create incremental updates to ViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, label, xcode4.5

I have a ViewController that requires a lot of data to be generated, this takes 5 seconds.

So the user doesn't think they haven't pressed the loading Tab the view appears immediately as I have kept ViewDidLoad sparse and the calculating routines are in ViewDidAppear. But it still takes 5 seconds for the results to materialise.

What is the mechanism for incrementally updating a label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty localized question and really depends on what your code looks like and what you're comfortable with doing.

If this were my code, I'd use either a timer (for predictable, periodic updating) or a delegate method to get a label to periodically update.  I might also show a UIActivityIndicator view adjacent to the label to show that an update is impending for it.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replaying. I can see where you're coming from. Will try that approach tomorrow and report back.This question is asked in different guises many times in StackOverflow as if people come from different programming backgrounds such tricks are simple but in OC++ it just works differently.